# A more useful basis under extension of scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Consider a field extension $L/K$ and a $K$-vector space $V$. 
The tensor product $L \otimes_K V$ with $\lambda (\alpha \otimes v) := (\lambda \alpha) \otimes v$ where $\lambda,\mu \in L$ makes it an $L$-vector space.

Identifying $v \in V$ with $1 \otimes v$, we get every $K$-basis of $V$ is an $L$-basis of $L \otimes V$. However,

> ... there exist **other bases of $L \otimes V$** where certain objects (e.g., linear operators) look simpler. *A Course in Algebra, Vinberg, page 299*

I am looking for interesting applications where such bases of $L \otimes V$ are shown to be indeed more useful.

Comment: What about a basis where an endomorphism is diagonalizable ? For instance, there exists endomorphisms $f:V\rightarrow V$ which are not diagonalizable, but become so in a field extension. A basis where $f$ is diagonal will not comes from $K$, so it is "another basis" and it may be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very concrete example: take $K = \Bbb R$, $L = \Bbb C$, and $V = \Bbb R^2$.  Take the linear transformation whose matrix with respect to the standard basis
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
If we choose the basis $\{(1,-i),(1,i)\}$, then the new matrix of the transformation is
$$
\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}
$$
In general, diagonalizing a transformation over a field extension is usually a good example of this phenomenon.  Another good example comes from the analysis of the Fibonacci numbers, in which we use the field extension $\Bbb Q((1 + \sqrt{5})/2)$.